# Case insensitive conservative substitution

Tags: search, substitute

Is there a built-in way in Vim to search for a pattern in a case-insensitive way, and substituting the occurrence conserving its case? (Something like an `s/abcd/efgh` that matches `AbCd` and replaces it with `EfGh`.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are ways to match characters case-sensitively, and replacement special forms that uppercase or lowercase their arguments, but there is not a native way to do that.

However, tpope has the excellent [vim-abolish](https://github.com/tpope/vim-abolish) which provides a command `:Subvert` that can accomplish this